# I want to count the number of prior agreements between firms and assign this count to the focal firm

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This how my database looks like:
([a screenshot from my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBbej.jpg))

```
+------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+------+
|         p_par          | fk_ior_sdc_alliances_id_par | pcusip_focal | cusip_partner | year |
+------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+------+
| "APA Ventures II"      |                         337 | "00185D"     | "032515"      | 1983 |
| "APA Ventures II"      |                         247 | "00185D"     | "46204Q"      | 1985 |
| "APA Ventures II"      |                         178 | "00185D"     | "032515 "     | 1985 |
| "APA Ventures II"      |                         335 | "00185D"     | "00282M "     | 1985 |
| "ARCO Chemical Co"     |                          85 | "001920"     | "45166A"      | 1985 |
| "ARCO Chemical Co"     |                          27 | "001920"     | "816077 "     | 1985 |
| "ARCO Chemical Co"     |                          98 | "001920"     | "22748D "     | 1985 |
| "ARI Technologies Inc" |                          79 | "00204K"     | "49461M "     | 1985 |
| "Abbott Biotech Inc"   |                         334 | "00282M"     | "00185D"      | 1982 |
| "Abbott Biotech Inc"   |                         334 | "00282M"     | " 00185D"     | 1983 |
| "Abbott Biotech Inc"   |                         335 | "00282M"     | "00185D"      | 1985 |
| "Abbott Biotech Inc"   |                         342 | "00282M"     | "89352X"      | 1985 |
| "Abbott Biotech Inc"   |                         329 | "00282M"     | "00790H "     | 1985 |
| "Aall Bank and Trust"  |                          40 | "00291B"     | "040453 "     | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         103 | "00358Q"     | "370476 "     | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         312 | "00358Q"     | "53655Q"      | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         367 | "00358Q"     | "12664T"      | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                          38 | "00358Q"     | "53655Q "     | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         333 | "00358Q"     | "69643R "     | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         195 | "00358Q"     | "74763I "     | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         269 | "00358Q"     | "87926F "     | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         164 | "00358Q"     | " 108046"     | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         328 | "00358Q"     | "88117R "     | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         442 | "00358Q"     | "595141 "     | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         243 | "00358Q"     | "34416D "     | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         237 | "00358Q"     | "827056 "     | 1985 |
| "Abingworth PLC"       |                         198 | "00358Q"     | "12465I "     | 1985 |
+------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+------+
```

I have a focal firm and its agreements with other firms. Mostly agreements are bilateral (meaning here only one partner), but there also multilateral ones. What I wanna do is to count prior agreements between the same firms. For example, in the `firts` row the focal firm's `cusip` is 74961D (PCUSIP_par) and partner's is 50590P. I wanna count how many times before 1980 this combination happened.

In case of multilateral agreements I intend to conduct combinations like Focal-partner_1, Focal- partner_2, Focal_partner_3 etc. Then I will sum count and will assign this number to the focal firm (in one row). I don't consider agreements between or among partners.

Expected data:

```
+----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+------+------------------+
|        p_par         | fk_ior_sdc_alliances_id_par | pcusip_focal | cusip_partner | year | prior_agreements |
+----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+------+------------------+
| "APA Ventures II"    |                         337 | "00185D"     | "032515 "     | 1983 |                0 |
| "APA Ventures II"    |                         178 | "00185D"     | "032515 "     | 1985 |                1 |
| "Abbott Biotech Inc" |                         334 | "00282M"     | " 00185D"     | 1982 |                0 |
| "Abbott Biotech Inc" |                         334 | "00282M"     | " 00185D"     | 1983 |                1 |
| "Abbott Biotech Inc" |                         335 | "00282M"     | " 00185D"     | 1985 |                2 |
+----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+------+------------------+
```

I am sure there is a code to tackle this issue.

Best regards, Farid

Comment: You'll have to clarify your logic: In your results, you have 5 rows. However, there are 7 rows where either the `pcusip_focal` or `cusip_partner` is `"00185D"`. This also doesn't reflect your original logic: "For example, in the firts row the focal firm's cusip is 74961D (PCUSIP_par) and partner's is 50590P."

Comment: this picture and an answer which you asked me to delete are different parts of data. I took 5 random rows to explain what I intend to get. In the picture I dont see any repeated agreements between two firms. If I explain on this picture I wanna check whether focal (74961D) and partner (50590P) met before or not. In other words, I wanna count prior rows where 74961D is the focal and 50590P is the partner.
I posted in on stata file, there is the discussion: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1465937-counting-prior-agreements
i need the same for mysql

Comment: @Zack, In this discussion i got stata version of that code: 
bys pcusip_focal cusip_partner (year): gen x = _n
bys pcusip_focal cusip_partner year (x): replace x = x - _n

(https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1465937-counting-prior-agreements)

Now I just need to translate it into mysql

Answer (score 0):

> I am sure there is a code to tackle this issue.

There certainly is. Generally, you should post whatever code you've tried already in your question. Also, it's bad form to post data in a picture, rather than providing it in a form that can be copied by others. You also only need to post the minimal data that someone will need to answer your question.

> For example, in the first row the focal firm's cusip is 74961D (PCUSIP_par) and partner's is 50590P. I wanna count how many times before 1980 this combination happened.

This is simple: Just add your conditions to your `WHERE` clause, and use the `COUNT` aggregate function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS agreement_count
FROM agreements
WHERE
    PCUSIP_par = '74961D'
    AND partner_cusip_1 = '50590P'
    AND sdc_year < 1980
```

> In case of multilateral agreements I intend to conduct combinations like Focal-partner_1, Focal- partner_2, Focal_partner_3 etc. Then I will sum count and will assign this number to the focal firm (in one row). I don't consider agreements between or among partners.

I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Maybe if you clarify your logic and provide some expected data.

With all that said, your data model really needs revisiting. It's generally a "code smell" when you have multiple columns with nearly the same name (as you do with `partner_cusip_1`, `partner_cusip_2`, and `partner_cusip_3`). For agreements with more than 4 parties, you'll have to start adding columns, which will greatly increase the overhead (writing queries, reducing performance, and making it easier to make mistakes).

I would recommend a different model: Storing your base agreement information (such as `sdc_year` and perhaps the "focal" firm) in one table, then storing your partner information in another table:

```
CREATE TABLE agreements
(
    agreement_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    sdc_year INT -- or have this be a TIMESTAMP, 
    PCUSIP_focal -- add a foreign key if you have a table of CUSIPs somewhere
)

CREATE TABLE agreement_partners
(
    agreement_id REFERENCES agreements(agreement_id),
    partner_cusip, -- add a foreign key if you have a table of CUSIPs somewhere
    PRIMRY KEY (agreement_id, partner_cusip)
)
```

With this table structure, your initial query (to figure out how many agreements between `74961D` and `50590P` before 1980 there were), your query becomes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS agreement_count
FROM agreements a
    INNER JOIN agreement_partners ap ON
        ap.agreement_id = a.agreement_id
WHERE
    a.sdc_year < 1980
    AND a.pcusip_focal = '74961D'
    AND ap.partner_cusip = '50590P'
```

Comment: Zack, thank your answer, I will come to other points but I wanna clarify a bit upfront. In the code (you provided in the end) I would get the count only for the first row. What I intend is to count for each row (each combination)

Comment: @FaridMammadaliyev, You'll have to clarify a bit what you need. Again, if you provide expected results and a simpler representation of your sample data, it might be a bit easier to figure out what you need.

Comment: I provided more detailed info below, I hope this explains what I need. I am looking forward to your answer.